# Why does my combobox selectedItem doesnt work?

Tags: java, javafx

I don't know why this line has an error

```
String selected = idCombo.GetItemText(idCombo.SelectedItem);
```

The compilation error is  `"SelectedItem cannot be resolved or is not a field"`

Comment: Those methods do not confirm to Java naming conventions, so it is unlikely that JavaFX has methods or properties with those names. In fact, it looks like you're trying to apply C# property names (eg C#'s `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox` has a `SelectedItem` property). Consult the JavaFX documentation for the actual method names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code looks like a C# code. In Java, you have to call `idCombo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()` instead of `idCombo.GetItemText(idCombo.SelectedItem)`.